# All DataGrid headers must have unique names - how to work around it

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatable

I am using a `DataGrid` with `AutogenerateColumns` set to `true`.

I'm binding it to a weakly-typed `DataTable` via its `DataContext` property.

The problem I've run into is that all the headers must have unique names, because `myGrid.Columns[x].Header` value is tied directly to the column name of the underlying `DataTable` (where, obviously, no duplicate column names are allowed).

Is there any sensible workaround?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your problem? Isnt DataTable doing what you want (uniqueness of column names) right?

Comment: I want to have non-unique headers in the `DataGrid` - display names; in UI! Without affecting column names in the `DataTable` (which  causes an exception to be thrown). I don't want the (visible) header names to be connected with (logical) column names at all; but as of now, they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is untested...

For DataGridHeaders to be changed, you would have to override their ContentTemplate.

```
    <DataGrid.Resources>   
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridColumnHeader}">
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
         <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock>
                      <TextBlock.Text>
                          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DynamicColumnHeaderTextConverter}">
                               <Binding BindsDirectlyToSource="True"/>
                               <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGrid}}" />
                          </MultiBinding>
                      </TextBlock.Text>
                   </TextBlock> 
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
     </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

In the above code DynamicColumnHeaderTextConverter's Convert() method will receive 2 values

1. Column Header i.e. DataTable Column Name
2. DataTable itself.

Based on this return the non-unique names.

```
    public class DynamicColumnHeaderTextConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
         public object Convert(object[] values, ...)
         {
              var columnName = (string)values[0];
              var dataTable = (DataTable)values[1]; //// if you want to decide name based on some value in the DataTable.
              switch(columnName)
              {
                   case "MyColumn1" : return "MyColumn";
                   case "MyColumn2" : return "MyColumn";
              }

              return columnName; 
         }
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tomorrow (I'm nearly done for today :)). Btw I've already overriden `DataGridColumnHeader` `ContentTemplate`, so I'll just incorporate the code you proposed. I will let you know

Comment: I tried that, but no unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm getting a XamlParseException: "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

Comment: Hey Vibo, sorry for the code mistake... <Binding Path="{Binding}" /> should be <Binding BindsDirectlyToSource="True"/>... I have edited my code above... sorry for the trouble again!

Comment: Thank you - but it doesn't work either. I created a small project out of your updated sample code at home now, and I got the same exception again: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I have no clue what it is. I'll keep on trying still.

Comment: Actually my mistake again... :) the second binding is wrong tooo... <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGrid}}" /> ... it must work now :-)

Comment: Yeah, great! Thanks for help. I have to say WPF is really baffling