# WPF grid wive column header styles

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caption

I have `DataGrid` in my wpf mvvm application. i am binding a data table as the data source from my view model. please tel me a way to bind `DataGrid` column header text with the underlying tada table column "Caption". (not the default column name). I create `Datagrid` columns automatically (`AuotGeneratedColumns = true`)

Comment: You have only one column header per column but you can have multiple rows. Which row in particular are you looking to bind the headers to? Or are you looking to bind them to another DataTable with a ColumnName - Caption mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution here ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928393/all-datagrid-headers-must-have-unique-names-how-to-work-around-it/6929089#comment-8293037

Let me know if this guides you in some direction?